# Windows 2000 Server with Interdev Users - how to find and change

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2000

I've inherited an Windows 2000 server with Interdev-enabled sites. I don't know how to find out which "interdev users" are mapped to domain/local accounts or how to change the users/passwords on an Interdev site. Someone mentioned they could do it with "FPSE" or "Interdev" but I'm not sure what that means.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to go into Interdev, create a new project or open an existing one, and:

1. Click the website
2. Choose Project -> Web Project -> Web Permissions.
3. Click "Users"
4. Add/Edit users for this site.

The Users and Groups on the web server will also show these users and the group that FPSE creates for these administrators.

Answer (score 0):

FPSE is FrontPage Server Extensions.  Visual Interdev uses Frontpage server extensions to talk to the server.

Look in the vti_ folders,  I believe on or more of the dlls is a isapi application you can use the manage the extensions.  There may also be editable files there to change things.  It has been many years since using VI and I don't remember the specifics.